# How to write tests that use Azure SDK?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, integration-testing

I'm wondering how I can write test, that will run in sonar, that will test the following method?

It seems almost impossible as sonar won't be able to actually get an azure subscription, so that will all have to be mocked.

Any help or pointers would be appreciated.

```
public AzureMetricRecords getVmMetrics(String azureSubscriptionId, String workspace, String vm, String metric, AggregationType aggregationType) {
    Azure azure = getAzure(azureSubscriptionId);

    String vmId = "/subscriptions/" + azureSubscriptionId + "/resourceGroups/" + workspace + "-" + vm +
            "/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/" + vm;

    VirtualMachine azureVm = azure.virtualMachines().getByResourceGroup(workspace + "-" + vm, vm);
    if (azureVm != null) {
        Map<String,MetricDefinition> metricsIndex = new HashMap<>();
        List<MetricDefinition> definitions = azure.metricDefinitions().listByResource(vmId);
        for (MetricDefinition d : definitions) {
            metricsIndex.put(d.name().value(), d);
        }

        if (!metricsIndex.containsKey(metric)) {
            throw new ValidationException("metric not found");
        }

        return getMetrics(DateTime.now(), metricsIndex.get(metric), aggregationType);
    } else {
        LOGGER.warn("getVmMetrics: Vm NOT found");

        AzureMetricRecords metricRecords = new AzureMetricRecords();
        metricRecords.setMetric(metric);
        metricRecords.setAggregation(aggregationType.name());
        return metricRecords;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you can not get a real object for your test, you use mocks (or stubs).

In your example, as I can see, you have to mock `getAzure()` method, so it returns a mock of `Azure` type. This mock, in order, has to provide proper implementations for this

```
azure.virtualMachines().getByResourceGroup(workspace + "-" + vm, vm);
```

and this

```
azure.metricDefinitions().listByResource(vmId);
```

methods.

For mocking you can use [Mockito](https://site.mockito.org/) framework, which provides a usefull API for creating and mocking objects and methods (using code or annotations).